# Edit GridView using a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that updates a table and the procedure will be called from a webform in a gridview.
I keep getting ***'Procedure or function FraudAlertUpdateMobileNo has too many arguments specified'*** and yet am passing the correct number of arguments
Below is my datasource code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="ConfigByAcct" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$         ConnectionStrings:FraudAlertsConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="FraudAlertsConfigAcct" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            UpdateCommand="FraudAlertUpdateMobileNo" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="inst"  Name="INSTID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtValue" Name="ACCTNUM" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int64" />
            </SelectParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="inst"  Name="INSTID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Type ="Int64" Name ="ACCTNUM" />
                        <asp:Parameter Type ="String" Name ="SMSAlertTo" />
                        <asp:Parameter Type ="String" Name ="FullName" />
                        <asp:Parameter Type ="String" Name ="Application" DefaultValue="AlertWeb" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Below is my procedure code

```
CREATEPROCEDURE [dbo].[FraudAlertUpdateMobileNo](
@InstID int,
@ACCTNUM  bigint,
@MobileNo varchar(500),
@FullName varchar(250),
@Application varchar(50)
) 
AS
```

Comment: Where is your procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Updating of the SqlDataSource and check the parameters

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int x = e.Command.Parameters.Count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:Parameter Type ="String" Name ="SMSAlertTo" />` // error is here. It should be  `<asp:Parameter Type ="String" Name ="MobileNo"/>`

Answer (score 0):

make sure the grid view has DataKeyNames attribute

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="ACCTNUM" >
```